# Params for functions in jupyter lab w/ Python

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm starting to use Jupyter lab which is nice.
One thing that I have a question about is how to get the param arguments for a function that I created?

If I do my_function() and then press the tab key, I get a long list of a variety of things that are present in my environment.   Such as other functions, classes, or instances (variables I defined), modules, and PARAM, which is what I care about.

It is nice that each of these are color coded, but is there an easy way to get to each of my params for my function without having to scroll through a million things?

For example in R, I can do

```
myfunction(<tab key>)
```

to get a list of all params for that function.

Answer (score 6):

press `shift`+`tab` with the cursor inside the function parenthesis to see the parameter arguments as well as the function docstring (if it has one).